# Можно ли обрабатывать Google Cloude Message вне приложения

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-android, sendmessage

Не могу разобраться с этим Google Cloud Message.
Задача стоит такая: я должен принимать все эти message из google cloud.
Вот из официального задания:

> Пуш уведомление должно содержать мини-иконку приложения, мини-картинку
> сообщения, заголовок, текст, развернутую картинку. И это сообщение при
> нажатии должно переводить на экран который указан в сообщении.

Как я это понимаю: я создаю сервис который наследуется от  FirebaseMessagingService его прописываю в манифесте. Я так понял что когда приложение не работает система выводит пуш уведомление. А когда приложение работает, то сообщение не выводиться идет обработка через FirebaseMessagingService и я могу это сообщение обработать сам и вызвать.
Но вот допустим приложение не работает пришло сообщение:

1. Я же его никак не могу обработать в своем коде, приложение то не работает?
2. Если это так то как мне его обработать в моей стартовой активности,
   которая стартует после клика на уведомление?

Comment: Что значит "экран который указан в сообщении"? Прямо в тексте?

Comment: Google Cloud Message (GCM) уже три года как выключен и не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Из документации

> FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notification messages have a predefined set of user-visible keys and an optional data payload of custom key-value pairs.

В случае не запущенного приложения (notification + payload)

> Notification: system tray.
> Data: in extras of the intent.

Т.е. отправляйте что вам надо в `payload` и получите это в интенте после клика на уведомление.

Источник:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive